# How do I hide the auto layout guides in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I find the new auto layout feature in Xcode quite useful. However Xcode always displays the auto layout constraints as blue guide lines. This is sometimes annoying because these guides are displayed at the centers and edges of the views right where also the resize handles are.

[image]

So sometimes I can't resize a view by dragging the handles because I just can't grab them. A click will always select the blue constraint guide line. (And I have to resize using the size inspector).

Is there a way to (temporarily) hide these constraint guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Xcode 4.5.2

To completely turn the new layout system off, just uncheck "Use Auto Layout" in the File Inspector:

[image]

Comment: :-) Sure, but I want to use auto layout, I just don't want to see the blue lines...

Comment: I am on Xcode 4.5.2 and the layout guides don't seem to be much of a problem here, but you can try holding down ⌥Option before resizing controls and see if that reduces the chances of selecting the guidelines. Alternatively, you can set OS X's Accessibility preferences to let you quickly zoom in on the screen with a key+scroll gesture for better precision while resizing. :)

Comment: You are right, in XCode 4.5.2 it is possible to click through the blue lines and resize the view by dragging. The constraint will not be selected anymore in this version. (Yet the cursor does not display the resize indicator). If you post an answer like "This is fixed in Xcode 4.5.2" I will accept that answer.

Answer (score 11):

In the main menu go to:

**Editor > Canvas > Show constraints** (toggle this to unchecked)

From this menu you can also show/hide layout and bounds rectangles, selection hgihlights and resize knobs.